# How did the increase in the birthrate and marriage impact on US homefront during WW2 (1939-1945)?

Tags: world-war-two, population

I tried to research the increase of birthrate and marriage of the US during WW2 (1939-1945), but the result just shows statistics after the war and the baby boom. Thus, they make me confused. I really need help!

I found this on WIKI, I need more information about the birthrate and marriage during the war, not after.

[Baby boom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_home_front_during_World_War_II)[edit]

> Marriage and motherhood came back as prosperity empowered couples who
>   had postponed marriage. The birth rate started shooting up in 1941,
>   paused in 1944–45 as 12 million men were in uniform, then continued to
>   soar until reaching a peak in the late 1950s. This was the "Baby Boom.
>
> In a New Deal-like move, the federal government set up the "EMIC"
>   program that provided free prenatal and natal care for the wives of
>   servicemen below the rank of sergeant. Housing shortages, especially
>   in the munitions centers, forced millions of couples to live with
>   parents or in makeshift facilities. Little housing had been built in
>   the Depression years, so the shortages grew steadily worse until about
>   1949, when a massive housing boom finally caught up with demand.
>   (After 1944 much of the new housing was supported by the G.I. Bill.)
>   Federal law made it difficult to divorce absent servicemen, so the
>   number of divorces peaked when they returned in 1946. In long-range
>   terms, divorce rates changed little.

Comment: What sources have you looked at and what is confusing you about the data they show?

Comment: i just update the information

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you looking for statistics on domestic birth and marriage rates?  Or are you looking for information on the impact of WWII on birth and marriage rates? Or on the impact of marriage rates on US society?  Each question will be answered by different sources.

Comment: I gonna need both of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still unsure what you are looking for, but there is a publication which might help.

- [VITAL STATISTICS RATES IN THE UNITED STATES 1940-196](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/vsus/vsrates1940_60.pdf)

(Note this is a *large* pdf file (887 pgs), so be patient on loading.)

---

Here is one specific chart concerning birth rates (pg 60, pdf pg 68):

[image]

A page earlier is marriage information (pg 59, pdf pg 67)::

[image]

These charts provide an overview of the changes in birth rate and marriage rate before, during and after the war.

Comment: So the number on the left column shows the amount of people were born by year? For example, in the birthrate chart, In 1910, the left column shows 30 (Rate per 1000 population). Thus, 30,000 people were born in 1910?

Comment: @Nhat No Birth *rate* is per 1000 to standardize the value for comparisons. It would be 30  times the (population in 1910/1000). More on birth rate calculations earlier in the pdf, and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_rate)

Comment: I still dont get it, what is the data on the left column? And you say "it would be 30 times" can u explain more clear to me?

Comment: Left column is birth rate. The number of births each year for 1000 people.  1910 shows, as you say, about 30.  Since the [US Population in 1910](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1910_United_States_Census) was  92,228,496 there would have been (statistically) 30*(92229496/1000) or about  2,766,855 births that year.

Comment: It is usually used just as an index to see the rate of change of a population, however, not to calculate actual number of births.

Answer (score 1):

In their book, ["Generations"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0688119123), William Strauss and Neil Howe opine that the "Baby Boom" began in 1943. Of course, they are not referring to the demographic phenomenon, which started in 1946, but rather cultural attitudes toward child rearing; that is, children born in 1943 were treated more like children born in 1946 than children born in 1940-41 (1942 was a transition year).

The hardships of the Depression were starting to dissipate by 1940, when the U.S. started gearing up for the approach of their involvement in World War II. That was the time Americans e.g. started re-introducing meat into their diets, if only in the form of e.g spam, that is canned spiced ham. (More fresh meat came after the war.) Even these small changes brought about the rise in marriage rates in 1941-42, and birth rates in 1942 (but more like 1943).

Parents were feeling optimistic about the future (in 1941, Life Magazine referred to the 20th century as the "American" century), and ready to "indulge" their children in small ways (more food and toys and "permissiveness), relative to the past. That created a wilder, looser bunch of kids beginning in 1943; (the "campus riots" started in 1965 when these kids turned 22).